# Oreo? No... Lollipop, maybe?

Tags: code-golf, string

Since 2009, Android's version code names have been confectionery-themed. Android 1.5 is Cupcake, Android 1.6 is Donut, Android 2.0 is Eclair, etc.. In fact, the version names are alphabetical!

```
C -> Cupcake
D -> Donut
E -> Eclair
F -> Froyo
G -> Gingerbread
H -> Honeycomb
I -> Ice Cream Sandwich
J -> Jellybean
K -> Kitkat
L -> Lollipop
M -> Marshmallow
N -> Nougat
O -> Oreo
```

In order:

```
Cupcake, Donut, Eclair, Froyo, Gingerbread, Honeycomb, Ice Cream Sandwich, Jellybean, Kitkat, Lollipop, Marshmallow, Nougat, Oreo
```

### Challenge

Write a **program/function** that takes a letter from `C` to `O` and outputs its respective Android version code name.

#### Specifications

- [Standard I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) **apply**.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are **forbidden**.
- You can choose to either support lowercase input or uppercase input or even both.
- The output may be in title case (`Cupcake`) or completely lower case (`eclair`). `Ice cream sandwich` may be capitalized however you like. (I didn't expect it to cause so much confusion...)
- This challenge is not about finding the shortest approach in all languages, rather, it is about finding the **shortest approach in each language**.
- Your code will be **scored in bytes**, usually in the encoding UTF-8, unless specified otherwise.
- Built-in functions (Mathematica might have one :P) that compute this sequence are **allowed** but including a solution that doesn't rely on a built-in is encouraged.
- Explanations, even for "practical" languages, are **encouraged**.

#### Test cases

These are uppercase and title case.

```
Input   Output

F       Froyo
I       Ice Cream Sandwich
J       Jellybean
N       Nougat
G       Gingerbread
L       Lollipop
```

In a few better formats:

```
F, I, J, N, G, L
f, i, j, n, g, l

F I J N G L
f i j n g l
```

Comment: @WheatWizard That's much harder though

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Are you saying its not a dupe because its easier?  This is a dupe precisely because it is an easier version of an existing question.  We've already done this type of question to death and this one provides absolutely nothing new or interesting to the genre.

Comment: @WheatWizard I think the former is a better dupe, since the latter is restricted source.

Comment: It might be a dupe of some other challenge. But _Help me recognize my monster_ is asking for string to symbol conversion (which leads to hash-based solutions). This one is asking for symbol to string.

Comment: FYI, It should be `Jelly Bean`, with a space. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Jelly_Bean

Comment: Darn, I lost the chance of incrementing everybody's byte count by 1.

Comment: If you want to be correct on the versions, you should probably just update it and tell people to change their answers.

Comment: No, that's a little too annoying, don't you think?

Comment: @totallyhuman you can do what I did on the nun challenge and update each one individually :P

Comment: Should it be `Ice Cream Sandwich` or `Ice cream sandwich`? The initial code block suggests the former but the test cases suggest the latter. The current winning answer requires `Ice cream sandwich`, but `The output may be in title case (Cupcake) or completely lower case (eclair).`.... `Ice cream sandwich` is not in title case.

Comment: `Ice Cream Sandwich` *is* title case. And, again, all of those are fine.

Comment: In `Ice cream sandwich` the `c` and `s` are not capitalized.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake. Updated. :)

Comment: [***coughs***](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html)

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Yeah, I saw that, too. Unfortunately, it doesn't include `MARSHMALLOW` and later.

Comment: [Closely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/9037/42963)

Comment: Note: Cupcake wasn't the first confectionary themed codename: Android 1.1 had the internal codename "Petit four" which is a small bite-sized confectionery, pastry or biscuit.

Answer (score 14):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 73 bytes

```
θ§⪪”%↖↙1¬¢/vy⁵⸿ψＪPP±≔Ｓ×5Jρνξ–Ｇu ◧；Yx³F▶ψ;εB↥:P¹N﹪J$α✂χ✳⦄⟲*±¶Sp:ς↘Ｖ◧◧”x℅θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AZ0AYv9jaGFyY29hbP//zrjCp@KqquKAnSXihpbihpkxwqzCoi92eeKBteK4v8@I77yqUFDCseKJlO@8s8OXNUrPgc69zr5/wpbvvKd1IOKXp@@8m1l4wrNG4pa2z4g7zrVC4oalOlDCuU7vuapKJM6x4pyCz4finLPipoTin7IqwrHCtlNwOs@C4oaY77y24pen4pen4oCdeOKEhc64//9p) I/O is in lower case. Based on this [verbose version](https://tio.run/##JY5BCoMwEADvfUXwZEBf4KnHnlroC9bNosE1m66xrq9Phd4GBobBGRQFuNaXxlTajx9uf7qXRwpk7TtzLG0jiU6UdTQkh0qwug1SOCLORsznSJAslgWKCXPMkg10m1dglsNkny6hJLZnhIVM0l4MGaKayikW00Q6XtnQdK6xxnfuqSEm4OvI@6FWrP239hv/AA). Explanation:

```
                Implicitly print:
θ               Input character
                Implicitly print:
   ”...”        Long compressed string "oneycombx...xingerbread"
  ⪪            Split on
        x       The string "x"
 §              Circularly indexed by
          ℅     Character code of
           θ    Input character
```

Comment: I... What? How.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Sorry I was too busy to add an explanation at the time. Hope this one suffices.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know it did compressed strings!

Comment: How Charcoal beats SOGL here is just unbelievable.

Comment: Jelly's still beating it :joy: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140092/73675

Comment: @Neil [you can just remove the comma in the verbose version :P](https://tio.run/##JY4xCsMwDAD3vsJ4iqF9QaaOnVroCxRZJCaK5SpOo7zeDXQ7ODgOJ1AU4NZemnLtPqG//OleHzmSde/CqXZeMh0oy2BIDpVgcSvkuCecjJiPgSBbqjNUE@ZUpBjoOi3ALLvJNp5CSWwrCDOZ5K0aMiQ1lUMs5ZF0OLPRO28@XN1TY8rA51AIfWvYbt92W/kH)

Answer (score 14):

## Bash + Core Utils <s>131</s> <s>128</s> <s>122</s> 117 bytes.

The script is encoded as Base64 because it contains special (weird) characters.

Accepts the Android codename letter **only in lowercase** as its first positional parameter. Returns the full codename **also in lowercase**.

```
CiPBUeICicG5tJ8W5a0Pc/hYuw7hkNMSIYkAPjARkdgFrdbh3NJgTmB4gRPiiQDJAaOyBH4ki14C
QDeKRNQJ8IJYER411DAnx0SO4CAKYmFzZTMyICQwfHRyICdBLVo0NwonICdhLXoKICd8Z3JlcCBe
JDEK
```

---

#### Explanation:

```
#�Q��������s�X����!�>0�������`N`x������~$�^@7�D�    ��X5�0'�D�� 
base32 $0|tr 'A-Z47
' 'a-z
 '|grep ^$1
```

- The first two lines are the binary blob with the data (see a the end of the answer for more information). The first line is empty, to avoid problems with Bash, as otherwise it may think that is being fed with a binary file.
- `base32 $0` encodes the script contents with Base32, with the default line wrapping of 76 characters.
- `tr 'A-Z47\n' 'a-z\n '` (note that the `\n` is written as a literal newline) will lowercase the input and replace ***4***, ***7*** and `\n` by `\n`, ***space*** and ***space*** respectively.
- `grep ^$1` will output the lines matching the string provided as first argument to the script.

---

#### Binary data

This octet stream was forged so it doesn't contain newlines and when it's decoded with Base32 as per RFC 4648, the resulting string is the list of Android codenames (using ***4*** as item delimiter and ***7*** to replace the *space* character). Among its peculiarities, it begins with a newline character and a hash (`#`) so it behaves as a comment and, therefore, isn't executed by the interpreter.

Also, the default line wrapping to 76 characters of this Base32 implementation helped me a byte, as I reordered the items to use the line break as one of the *Ice cream sandwich* spaces.

---

Also, and going a bit off-topic, I think that Google shouldn't <s>in</s>directly advertise commercial products in the Android codenames.

Comment: Nice, this is a really cool answer! Welcome to the site :)

Comment: Another Bash answer: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140147/41835

Comment: This version is buggy, at least on my system (bash 4.4.12, coreutils 8.27). For `f`, it outputs two lines: one with `froyo` and another with mysterious `fgeyltmuzteibno`.

Comment: @MarSoft: Thanks! Fixed. The pity is that now I need a byte more.

Comment: @MarSoft: Solved! Now with the same bytes!

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 57 bytes

```
Oị“¡ȥọ⁴ḷæĿɱ}#n#i®ÞSỊ3ƙɼıjṁ)-⁵g7ḥjC?4ƘẠʂ+ḋ¤⁺jṣð£?v»Ḳ¤F⁾! y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AXMAjP9qZWxsef//T@G7i@KAnMKhyKXhu43igbThuLfDpsS/ybF9I24jacKuw55T4buKM8aZybzEsWrhuYEpLeKBtWc34bilakM/NMaY4bqgyoIr4biLwqTigbpq4bmjw7DCoz92wrvhuLLCpEbigb4hIHn///9j)

-5 thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan).

Comment: Save four bytes by using a placeholder for the spaces in "ice cream sandwich" and using spaces for splitting, for example: `Oị“¡ḟ¤Y7bh%XO€ḥıṣẎṄṢ°ḊḞİỌĿż0Y⁷ẠỵƈƭV>tÐNY_LɠðṅẒọX?v»Ḳ¤F⁾! y`

Comment: ...actually make that five bytes (I had used "lair" when "clair" is in the dictionary): `Oị“¡ȥọ⁴ḷæĿɱ}#n#i®ÞSỊ3ƙɼıjṁ)-⁵g7ḥjC?4ƘẠʂ+ḋ¤⁺jṣð£?v»Ḳ¤F⁾! y`

Comment: @JonathanAllan thanks...wait why would I need the `F`? oh it's because I get input as a string not char

Answer (score 11):

## Bash + Core Utils (Grep): <strike>132</strike> 130 Bytes

Simple as could be

```
grep ^$1<<<'Cupcake
Donut
Eclair
Froyo
Gingerbread
Honeycomb
Ice Cream Sandwich
Jellybean
Kitkat
Lollipop
Marshmallow
Nougat
Oreo'
```

Comment: Input via `dd` is clever, but could you save as a script and use `$1` instead?

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 139 bytes

```python
lambda x:x+'upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,ce cream sandwich,ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo'.split(",")[ord(x)-67]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BDoIwEADvvqLxQhtXY2KChkQ/oh6WUmDj0m2WEuH1yMHjzBwmLbmXeFnb@2tlHOoGzVzNh2JKHj8BJE4ZPCMpqCwCFLugtQZsthQWL0MNPhi/mcGMGJsv@R4C81IHjED5gxmEmZIkQB37AZnlCzJ1W9AgxWlMTNnuYe@eoo2d3bG8vtdW1JChaBS3pS2vcDu7ameSUszW92rJQXF8FND@ybn1Bw)

Answer (score 8):

## C++, <s>206</s> <s>201</s> 198 bytes

*Thanks to @sergiol for helping to save 3 bytes!*

```
#import<cstdio>
void f(int l){char*w[]={"upcake","onut","clair","royo","ingerbread","oneycomb","ce Cream Sandwich","ellybean","itkat","ollipop","arshmallow","ougat","reo"};printf("%c%s",l,w[l-67]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZDBjoMgEIbvPAVh06hbe91NqvbSB9jDHrs94EiVdGQI4hpjfHYXbLJcfvjnA@YfsPbUAmzbm@4tOV/C4BtNF/ZLuuGPVBvPMVugk@59ut2rRYwW5FOJXJAZfRBAqV1QRzMF0aZVrnZKNjuiZqC@jpji1@D2/FuaZtLQBU8hzrWSJl7zTxlfI0RtyYaddEPXS0Saoj22e9kpEmthXWjrkYoDHAaRYz7d8PTxec@KNcQwgGOjeKlp8PHDC2MxRC@1STO2MB7WgxxPYyaOVXJNCo5llXwFPR4x24kXt7MpZsX/KUznfAYaPS9LLn6MeJVWtm5/)

## C, 173 bytes

```
f(l){char*w[]={"upcake","onut","clair","royo","ingerbread","oneycomb","ce Cream Sandwich","ellybean","itkat","ollipop","arshmallow","ougat","reo"};printf("%c%s",l,w[l-67]);}
```

Well, it started as C++, but now it's also valid C, and some bytes can be saved by compiling it as C.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY@xjoMwDIZ3niKKVBGudL0OlKkPcEPHqoNJA0Q1SWRACCGenTq0Oi@//fuzZetTo/W21QqzRbdAP9P9US5yDBpeRubSu3Fg0QiWWMnPnsW6xlBFBp47YmbtuypiRlzZ7cQN3HOyumXPIM6VARfHhhfEbR7RBh84A@rbDhD9FO2x2dtkvFyLQNYNtZIHfehljvl0x9Pv@ZEV68YN0YF1KkuWRHDUnoSK5wss02taCLyU6R/r8YjZTny4neVXi/8qjEOvpPw6a7Jubw)

Comment: My failed attempt to turn it shorter by removing the first letter of each entry: https://tio.run/##TZCxboMwEIZ3nsJyFAEJ6dgqAbLkATp0pAzGGLBy@CxjCyHEs1Obqbd81n@/T/8d1/rWc77vJ6k4uFaQYrKtxI/hGTFnkXSJVJZAuvKBmctc1eVKnebsLWhGUTnrwYFJ42lwQQ@pemEaI1h7WMTCcWyCTZCXV0fyw1Q7Sz54TQAsjWAqfLNvFqYhgNSo/YuZaRgZAM5Bdv3RNgLploc0RFf3e51P2viIXaIzeubniWaQzRXcPr/qNDfCOqPIRefbvw0lTjYEeUZRWG5kUiVptEbEV4eGJMd0KONXnBMoyvjb83qF9HCE8jd6PDg6S4rCnwjSQPqraB5t@x8

Comment: @sergiol Thanks! I was able to save three bytes with that after a bit of golfing.

Comment: `#import` in c++? what am I missing here?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal: IIRC I think some compiling warning advised me also  to add `#import <cstdio>` because the lack of `#include <stdio.h>`; or may be I am wrong

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal It's not standard C++, but at least GCC and MSVC have it.

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>137</s> 136 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to Neil*

```js
c=>'CupcakeDonutEclairFroyoGingerbreadHoneycombIce Cream SandwichJellybeanKitkatLollipopMarshmallowNougatOreo'.match(c+'([a-z]| .)+')[0]
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

c=>'CupcakeDonutEclairFroyoGingerbreadHoneycombIce Cream SandwichJellybeanKitkatLollipopMarshmallowNougatOreo'.match(c+'([a-z]| .)+')[0]

;[...'CDEFGHIJKLMNO'].map(c => console.log(c, '->', f(c)))
```

Comment: can't you include the space in the character range, probably with \s? haven't used much JS Regex

Comment: @michi7x7 Hes need the match to stop at an uppercase letter except in the case of Ice Cream Sandwich, although `([a-z]| .)+` (saving 1 byte) would work even with Ice Cream Sandwich in the middle of the string (it would start failing when code names reached S though).

Comment: @Neil well, `[a-z\s]+` doesn't match uppercase letters. I just don't know if you can do that in JS

Comment: @michi7x7 So how would it work with Ice Cream Sandwich?

Comment: Use `Ice cream sandwich`, like in the test case (although this is not Title Case)

Comment: @michi7x7 Ah, yes. I didn't notice it was allowed. Thanks!

Comment: @michi7x7 Ah, I see proper case is allowed too so yes `[ a-z]+` would work in that case.

Answer (score 5):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ethproductions/japt/), <s>81</s> 79 bytes

Contains a few characters that won't display here.

```
U+`Æ+tfÆ÷¯kef©fclairfê $ßdfey¬mbf­ ×Äm ÑØrfÁKÞ fkfo¥ipopfÂâÚaow`qf gUc
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=VStgxit0ZpzG969rZWaNqWZjbGFpcmae6gGgJN+EZGaNZXmsbWJmrSDXxG0g0YDYcmbBS94gZoprhWZvpWlwb3BmwuLaYW93YHFmIGdVYw==&input=IkUi)

- 2 bytes saved thanks to [Oliver](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61613/oliver).

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of uppercase character string `U`.

A compressed string (everything between the backticks) of the names, separated with an `f` and without their first letter is split (`q`) into an array on `f`.

Within that array we get the element at the index (`g`) of `U`s character code. (Yay, index wrapping!)

We append that to `U` and implicitly output the resulting string.

Comment: Nice. You can save a couple bytes if you split on `f` instead if newlines: https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=VStgxit0ZpzG969rZWaNqWZjbGFpcmae6gGgJN+EZGaNZXmsbWJmrSDXxG0g0YDYcmbBS94gZoprhWZvpWlwb3BmwuLaYW93YHFmIGdVYw==&input=Ikoi

Comment: @Oliver: Oh, nice, thanks :) On my phone, walking down the street so definitely wouldn't have gotten that for a while (if at all).

Answer (score 5):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>137</s> <s>134</s></sub> 132  Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input as expected type `Variant\String` and length `1` holding a **capital** letter from cell `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window function

```vba
?[A1]Split("upcake onut clair royo ingerbread oneycomb ce cream sandwich ellybean itkat ollipop arshmallow ougat reo")(Asc([A1])-67)
```

-5 Bytes for changing the spaces in `ce cream sandwich` from   (char 32) to  <s>(char 160)</s>  `` (char 127) and removing comma delimiter in the `Split` function

Answer (score 4):

## [SOGL V0.12](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), 81 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
]&ŗ√‰fō¶č▓'▼$»3↕█γb└a}⅟∑─b¹¦Æ:↕┘∞½Σ#gī±⅔≡≥\3Qy-7todΥ7ā‼D←εPρρ:¬c‰ƨ}fæ²‘θ╔@ŗz,WHHw
```

[Try it Here!](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTVEJTI2JXUwMTU3JXUyMjFBJXUyMDMwZiV1MDE0RCVCNiV1MDEwRCV1MjU5MyUyNyV1MjVCQyUyNCVCQjMldTIxOTUldTI1ODgldTAzQjNiJXUyNTE0YSU3RCV1MjE1RiV1MjIxMSV1MjUwMGIlQjklQTYlQzYlM0EldTIxOTUldTI1MTgldTIyMUUlQkQldTAzQTMlMjNnJXUwMTJCJUIxJXUyMTU0JXUyMjYxJXUyMjY1JTVDM1F5LTd0b2QldTAzQTU3JXUwMTAxJXUyMDNDRCV1MjE5MCV1MDNCNVAldTAzQzEldTAzQzElM0ElQUNjJXUyMDMwJXUwMUE4JTdEZiVFNiVCMiV1MjAxOCV1MDNCOCV1MjU1NEAldTAxNTd6JTJDV0hIdw__,inputs=aQ__)

Explanation:

```
...‘            push "cupcake donut eclair froyo gingerbread honeycomb ice_cream_sandwich jellybean kitkat lollipop marshmallow nougat oreo"
    θ           split on spaces
     ╔@ŗ        replace underscores with spaces
        z,W     find the inputs index in the lowercase alphabet
           HH   decrease by 2
             w  get that item from the array
```

Now there is a shorter [80 byte](https://dzaima.github.io/SOGLOnline/?code=JTVEJTI2JXUwMTU3JXUyMjFBJXUyMDMwZiV1MDE0RCVCNiV1MDEwRCV1MjU5MyUyNyV1MjVCQyUyNCVCQjMldTIxOTUldTI1ODgldTAzQjNiJXUyNTE0YSU3RCV1MjE1RiV1MjIxMSV1MjUwMGIlQjklQTYlQzYlM0EldTIxOTUldTI1MTgldTIyMUUlQkQldTAzQTMlMjNnJXUwMTJCJUIxJXUyMTU0JXUyMjYxJXUyMjY1JTVDM1F5LTd0b2QldTAzQTU3JXUwMTAxJXUyMDNDRCV1MjE5MCV1MDNCNVAldTAzQzEldTAzQzElM0ElQUNjJXUyMDMwJXUwMUE4JTdEZiVFNiVCMiV1MjAxOCV1MDNCOCV1MjU1NEAldTAxNTd6JTJDVyV1MjA3RXc_,inputs=aQ__) version, but I added the +2/-2 built-ins because of this challenge :p

The compressed string is split like `"cup","cake"," donut eclair fro","yo gingerbread honeycomb ice","_","cream","_","sandwich jelly","bean kit","kat loll","i","pop marsh","mallow"," nougat oreo"` for maximum usage of english words (many weren't in SOGLs dictionary), right now I can't find any improvements.

Answer (score 4):

## [Cubically](https://github.com/aaronryank/cubically), <s>1047</s> <s>852</s> 830 bytes

<sup>Functions sure help golf large programs...</sup>

```
⇒+552
⇒+551
⇒+553
⇒+55
⇒/1+52
⇒/1+53
~@7+4f5=?{:5+53@:4/1f1@:5+51@:5+2/1f4@:5+3/1f2@:2/1f2@}
+5f5=?{:3/1f1@:2/1f1@:5+53@:5+3/1f1@}
+51f5=?{:5+51@+1@:5+2/1f4@:5+1/1+551@+1@}
+52f5=?{:5+1/1f1@:3/1f1@:4/1f3@:3/1f1@}
+53f5=?{:5+1/1f2@:2/1f1@:4/1f2@:2/1f2@:5+1/1f1@:5+3/1f4@:5+1/1f1@:2/1f2@:5+2/1f4@:1/1f2@}
+53=?{:3/1f1@:2/1f1@-1@:4/1f3@:5+51@:3/1f1@:1/1f1@:5+3/1f4@}
+1f6=?{:5+51@:2/1f2@:5/1+3@:4/1+52@:5+1/1f1@:2/1f2@:5+2/1+55@:1/1f1@:5/1+3@:2/1+54@:5+2/1f4@6:2/1f1@6:1/1f2@6:2/1f3@6:5+1/1f2@6:5+51@6:5/1f2@6}
+2f6=?{:2/1f2@:5+52@@:4/1f3@:5+3/1f4@:2/1f2@:5+2/1f4@:2/1f1@}
+3f6=?{:5+1/1f2@:5+3/1f1@-1@:5+2/1f4@:5+3/1f1@}
+4f6=?{:3/1f1@:5+52@@:5+1/1f2@:4/1f1@:3/1f1@:4/1f1@}
+5f6=?{:5+2/1f4@:5+1/1f1@:5+2/1f1@:5/1f2@:1/1f1@:5+2/1f4@:5+52@@:3/1f1@:2/1f3}
+51f6=?{:3/1f1@:5+53@:4/1f2@:5+2/1f4@:5+3/1f1@}
+52f6=?{:5+1/1f1@:2/1f2@:3/1f1@}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJLagMxDN3PVUwpkuwpDIR6m2OkgUAg2y5CaLfZ94i9yESyZNlxks1oJD89PX3231/H/e50Oq/r//UvpISTWjBLZqff/BHiO4SEm8/LkkKivLB/gCxO@SK7UX6IfzAvWMzPFJLnkWagJ1LFQwFCXwFyuOctrxoWMHZgUEbjF2FUPYHSAEXXEHutjUhFxS7iCJMD3h09dPbWNOhw7HUg5@TSEnnDXoXDOmCW/UIEj6IxKr5EYxM5m57Z1KpPbOsYZq07C4O4LAldkldjDV1DNplxIFinTV1PUEHkgxkOpaRETyE/DanpBPFhv@CXZaVwWJhGdDhCcReOXqJbHPkJDlLI7@SZ@IRDw21RhlnX7Q0) This is 830 bytes in [Cubically's SBCS](https://github.com/aaronryank/Cubically/wiki/Code-page).

- `~` reads input, `@` prints it. (This breaks when the input is invalid.)
- Each of the `+.../...+...=7?6{...}` compares the input to each ASCII value (`C`, `D`, `E`, `F`, etc) and executes the code within `{...}` if they are equal.
- Each code block (`{...}`) prints the rest of the name (the first character is already printed).

Thanks to [TehPers' ASCII to Cubically translator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/135775/61563) which was very helpful.

Comment: That's 1060 bytes

Answer (score 4):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 181 bytes

```
!vi:od5*-0$6a*@p!
v<
 v"upcake"
 v"onut"
 v"clair"
 v"royo"
 v"ingerbread"
 v"oneycomb"
 v"ce Cream Sandwich"
 v"ellybean"
 v"itkat"
 v"ollipop"
 v"arshmallow"
 v"ougat"
 v"reo"
o<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY0xDoMwDEV3TgGoE1KlLu1QoapSx449gUlcsDBxFEgQp09pwvbk//z/l@YhxirQXfS1OV9ON2ietipCW5Sh9lbBiPUfxfglgWIgl8jJJgnI9Og6h6APFTclU5d1LF97MpUfMHolNaQrMm8dgsnvywi5W5jJik0Mbh4mYJY1R74/JIf7qrSPGN8/)

This works by self-modifying the program to place a `<` in front of the correct name to print, the position of which is determined by the value of the inputted letter.

Answer (score 3):

## Dyalog APL, <s>158</s> <s>143</s> 131 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @Zacharý*

*12 bytes saved thanks to @Gil*

```apl
{⍵,(⎕A⍳⍵)⊃','(1↓¨=⊂⊢)',,,upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,ce Cream Sandwich,ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY47CsJAFACvkm4VnoUHsJD4/xae4GWzxsWXvLAmhCA2CikCEUG8gJW9eAGPshfR7YaZZjClTlgicfT7bW11O9rmAy17ffRt83bctvVFgGh1bXX/vnq2Ptv62RYAkKcS9wo4yTOQhNqA4ZJBJ5EygVEYuqRKyXEAUnm@M7G3wSQstNyBIioDhQnobI8ZMJFOOQU0h12MRFwA55ELRrE4uTPv@xL@YDgaT6az@WK5Wos/)

**How?**

`',,,upcake...'` - list of words

`','(1↓¨=⊂⊢)` - split by `','`

`(⎕A⍳⍵)⊃` - take from the place of the argument in the alphabet

`⍵,` - and append to the letter

Comment: Why did you describe `↑` as flatten?

Comment: Also, `{⍵,∊⍬⍬'upcake' 'onut' 'clair' 'royo' 'ingerbread' 'oneycomb' 'ce cream sandwich' 'ellybean' 'itkat' 'ollipop' 'arshmallow' 'ougat' 'reo'[⎕A⍳⍵]}` works for 1 less byte!

Comment: @Zacharý because it is... "mix". nice one! why ∊ and not ↑?

Comment: Because `∊` is flatten as well, but actually flatten and not "mix". `↑(1 2)(3 4)` is NOT flat, while `∊(1 2)(3 4)` is.

Comment: @Zacharý OP changed that... AGAIN.

Comment: Use a single string for all and partition it to save another 12 bytes: {⍵,(⎕A⍳⍵)⊃','(1↓¨=⊂⊢)',,,upcake,onut,....

Comment: Do as Gil said, that is amazing.

Comment: @Gil nice one! I tried with regex before but it was too long.

Comment: Too tired to think clearly now, but another option is to skip separators and only use an initial capital letter for each version and partition it that way (you might find a way to shorten the expression further): 'ABCupcakeDonutEclair..'∘{⍺/⍨(+\⍺∊⎕A)∊⎕A⍳⍵}'D'

Comment: @Gil I think I have an even shorter solution, but I'm afk til tomorrow, so I'll test it when I get to the ws

Comment: Yeah, going off of Gil's comment, `{⍵/⍨(+\⍵∊⎕A)∊⎕A⍳⍞}'...'` should save 1 more byte than Gil's suggestion.

Comment: [Outgolfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140243/55550)

Comment: Outgolf Zacharý with Gil's suggestion: [`(⎕A⍳⍞)⊃'ABCup…Oreo'(∊⊂⊣)⎕A`](https://tio.run/##Vc49DoIwGMbx3VOwiYOHwC9EEc/w0jbQ8NK3qRDSVQcNiW6uLh7BG/UiKIlLn@33TH/QOOcWkIrB3a6R4oYkH0L3eEbu/nH318z1l2m0WLaaQSVWpNpmzRCk2RiyFEtVCJMbAXxLSlhGdZ4wEbDfUwcnULyTrNwJRJsLUHvZVNCkhCg16QOYU1kDInUZtQU0RyNoGrpb7/qz69@zsWLMGoJx/7jJZuIx8bnzmfmMfaZf)

Comment: I *could* steal that solution, but considering I was inspired by "I think I have an even shorter solution," so I won't do the whole percent mess again (Answers going between me and Cowsquack, which ended up with like 4 APL answers).

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>195</s> <s>192</s> 190 bytes

-2 bytes thanks to @Quentin

```c
*V[]={"upcake","onut","clair","royo","ingerbread","oneycomb","ce Cream Sandwich","ellybean","itkat","ollipop","arshmallow","ougat","reo"};main(c,v)char**v;{printf("%c%s",c,V[(c=*v[1])-67]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYy7CoQwEEV/RQKChlhss1uI1bbbLdiIxThmNZgX8YWI355NrM5w5t6LxYDoPa2btjrJahEmThgxel0CUIJwgc4cJkDogbvOcejvCD/QqC7GePIOViVf0P0ucAyOS3l0HHSsLRPENSOlsMaGC9w8KpDS7FGvw/123JCrVCB0hmzLcQRH6Vae1gm9/DKSYjoThqxuMqzo1jzavHi@2ry8vPefPw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 158 bytes

```
proc A s {puts $s[lindex {upcake onut clair royo ingerbread oneycomb "ce Cream Sandwich" ellybean itkat ollipop arshmallow ougat reo} [expr [scan $s %c]-67]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dco7DoMwEEXRrTwhUqZNapTsICWiMMMILAaP5Y8AIdbuuL3nJpJSfFBCh4jL5xTRxl6sm/jAlT2ZlaEuJ5AYGxD0VFg3cxgDm6kSn6TbiIYYn5o2/IybdktLAxY5RzYONq0mQUWsVw8T4rIZEd2hea4QWG/0fPiAPlL924gHDc/Xexju0uFbyh8)

Comment: Tcl! You don't see too many Tcl solutions on here. It's a shame.

Answer (score 3):

## EXCEL, 154 bytes

```
=A1&CHOOSE(CODE(A1)-66,"upcake","onut","clair","royo","ingerbread","oneycomb","ce Cream Sandwich","ellybean","itkat","ollipop","arshmallow","ougat","reo")
```

Comment: I've never thought of using excel in this way. Perfect. Now do it with WORD

Comment: @tisaconundrum - we do not speak of that accursed thing; Even VBA could not save it

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), <s>117</s> 116 bytes

Port of [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140076/59487).

```
+Q@c"upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,ce cream sandwich,ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo"\,a67C
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BQ%40c%22upcake%2Conut%2Cclair%2Croyo%2Cingerbread%2Coneycomb%2Cce+cream+sandwich%2Cellybean%2Citkat%2Collipop%2Carshmallow%2Cougat%2Creo%22%5C%2Ca67C&input=%22C%22&debug=0)** or **[Check out the Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BQ%40c%22upcake%2Conut%2Cclair%2Croyo%2Cingerbread%2Coneycomb%2Cce+cream+sandwich%2Cellybean%2Citkat%2Collipop%2Carshmallow%2Cougat%2Creo%22%5C%2Ca67C&input=%22C%22&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22C%22%0A%22D%22%0A%22E%22%0A%22F%22%0A%22G%22%0A%22H%22%0A%22I%22%0A%22J%22%0A%22K%22%0A%22L%22%0A%22M%22%0A%22N%22%0A%22O%22&debug=0)**

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 99 bytes (70 characters)

*-15 bytes thanks to [@insert_name_here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59682/insert-name-here)!*

```
+Q@c." y|çEC#nZÙ¦Y;åê½9{ü/ãÑª#¤
ØìjX\"¦Hó¤Ê#§T£®úåâ«B'3£zÞz~Ð£ë"\,a67C
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BQ%40c.%22+y%08%7C%C3%A7%C2%85%C2%87EC%23nZ%C3%99%C2%A6Y%3B%C3%A5%C3%AA%C2%BD%C2%819%06%7B%C3%BC%2F%C3%A3%C3%91%C2%8A%C2%AA%23%06%C2%95%12%C2%A4%0A%C3%98%C3%AC%1AjX%5C%22%C2%8E%0F%C2%93%C2%A6H%C3%B3%C2%90%C2%A4%C3%8A%23%1D%0B%1D%C2%A7T%C2%85%C2%A3%04%07%10%C2%99%1D%C2%AE%18%C3%BA%C3%A5%C2%91%C3%A2%0B%C2%91%C2%ABB%14%273%C2%A3z%C3%9Ez%7E%C2%81%C3%90%16%C2%A3%C3%AB%19%22%5C%2Ca67C&input=%22C%22&debug=0)**

Comment: You could save 15 bytes by [using compressed strings](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2BQ%40c.%22+y%08%7C%C3%A7%C2%85%C2%87EC%23nZ%C3%99%C2%A6Y%3B%C3%A5%C3%AA%C2%BD%C2%819%06%7B%C3%BC%2F%C3%A3%C3%91%C2%8A%C2%AA%23%06%C2%95%12%C2%A4%0A%C3%98%C3%AC%1AjX%5C%22%C2%8E%0F%C2%93%C2%A6H%C3%B3%C2%90%C2%A4%C3%8A%23%1D%0B%1D%C2%A7T%C2%85%C2%A3%04%07%10%C2%99%1D%C2%AE%18%C3%BA%C3%A5%C2%91%C3%A2%0B%C2%91%C2%ABB%14%273%C2%A3z%C3%9Ez~%C2%81%C3%90%16%C2%A3%C3%AB%19%22%5C%2Ca67C&input=%22C%22&debug=0) (though the answer would have to contain unprintable characters then).

Comment: @insert_name_here Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 110 bytes

```
:c“reo“upcake“onut“clair“royo“ingerbread“oneycomb“ce Cream Sandwich“ellybean“itkat“ollipop“arshmallow“ougat”=+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYwxDsMwCEWvkr03qNQpU@eeADvIQcHGIrEibz1Ie7lexIEu8PXehwQEY9zj7/1RFJutRtjQgpR22IoMpG6lu6aSUIMiLP8K9ig5eA2n2WieXlCWk@JqDJl7QCh@dmzg34SZqlRLoPuagVlOxy25/j5uYzwv)

#### Explanation

```
:          Push two copies of the input
 c         Get the codepoint of the top one
  “...”    Push the list of version names without their first letters
       =   Modularly index the code point into the list
        +  Append to the input
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 145 bytes

```
f c=takeWhile(/=succ c)$dropWhile(/=c)"CupcakeDonutEclairFroyoGingerbreadHoneycombIce Cream SandwichJellybeanKitkatLollipopMarshmallowNougatOreo"
```

Comment: `takeWhile` can be `fst.span` and `dropWhile` accordingly `snd.span`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 128 bytes

```java
c->c+"upcake#onut#clair#royo#ingerbread#oneycomb#ce Cream Sandwich#ellybean#itkat#ollipop#arshmallow#ougat#reo".split("#")[c-67]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NU/LbgIxDLzzFVYipF0VcmylPpAqWvqkPXBEHLzZLASycZQHaFXx7dtA6cGyNTO2Z7a4xzE5Zbf1rnepMlqCNBgCzFFb@BkAXNAQMea2J11Dm7liEb226@UK0K9DeZYCbPM9kaI2oklWRk1WzC7D/XSDHmVUfvS3OoEGHqCX44m8YslJ3ClONkWeDWjPPXXEs0z5yiusM6U6SW3FpYJpRlpYoK0PWm64MqarFFqu4w4jJ2O0I8fRh02LxtCBU1pnwitiIjijY8E4K5dyfH2z6u/OzhvyUMhsEcItsOnT8@zl9e3943P@9c1EpJP5R@@xK8r/rACLLkTVCkpRuJwoNgUb5u1hGFo2CiNoBDpnuiKU5d@T4@BUx/4X)

---

## Using regexes, 149 bytes

```java
s->"CupcakeDonutEclairFroyoGingerbreadHoneycombIce cream sandwichJellybeanKitkatLollipopMarshmallowNougatOreo".replaceAll(".*?("+s+"[a-z ]+).*","$1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVDJbgIxDL33K6yoSDMskXrtQoXY9wNHxMETMhDIxFGSAU0rvp2GpQfL1vOzn58PeMIWWWkO2@PVlplWAoRG72GOysDvC8AT9QFDTCdSWyhiL1kFp8xuvQF0O5/eqQCHuI@XQWmel0YERYYPnsVnd48ORZCu@RhtQw5fcPWtNuuWVuBR9siUoR/1lRs4qmgYWdJlTuJ2REZWgopsLCSIiBTg0WzPSuwnUusqk2imKhwxzEhrZcnO0fl9gVrTeUHlDsPSSWLcSatRyI7WCeP174Q1fIOtsfUDm0bK66zJXt9Yev2428nJQSLi3eDfgXV7/cFwNJ5MZ/PFkvFAN0cd57BK0v8HAKwqH2TBqQzcRpshT1gtTtd8zbCmb0LO0VpdJT5NHyKXl1tcrn8)

- 4 bytes saved on the regex solution thanks to Kevin Cruijssen!

Comment: Was about to post the same `.split` answer (only with different delimiter) when I read the challenge and couldn't find a Java answer (until I went to the second page of answers), so +1. As for the regex answer, `([a-z]| .)+` can be `[a-z ]+`, since you are allowed to output "Ice cream sandwich" ("_The output may be in title case (Cupcake) or completely lower case (eclair). Ice cream sandwich may be capitalized however you like. (I didn't expect it to cause so much confusion...)_")

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 127 bytes

```
->c{c+%w[upcake onut clair royo ingerbread oneycomb ce\ Cream\ Sandwich ellybean itkat ollipop arshmallow ougat reo][c.ord-67]}
```

Takes uppercase input. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcmxDoIwEIDhWZ/iFsNgdNRJFwajMS6O0OEoBzSUXlPakMb47JXFpNuX/3ehiam7pMNVfuR@t1TBShwJ2AQPUqNy4DgyKNOTaxxhuy6KkqcGJNVQrmmq4Y2mXZQcgLSODaEB5Uf0wForyxbQzcOEWvMCHPp1OGJRySO79nA6i2@ywc/QVUVZiO3f98yPzK/Mt8zPQmzSDw)

Answer (score 1):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 125 bytes

```
Ccupcake
donut
eclair
froyo
gingerbread
honeycomb
ice cream sandwich
jellybean
kitkat
lollipop
marshmallow
nougat
oreoÇ^"/d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcnBDcMgDADAv5/99hN1gQ7RPSoZ44CLwYhAo0yQwToYzffuO@eLRiVMDN7K6MCkKA3WZodBkBK4ucboIVrhgyw7EOKFLsvLhsXvQhE@rHo4xgJJesIOaqpSrULGtsWMqrZDsRGus8Z2/53v2@Pp51z/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Recursiva](https://github.com/officialaimm/recursiva), <s>130 119</s> 118 bytes

```
+aYQ'upcake!onut!clair!royo!ingerbread!oneycomb!ce cream sandwich!ellybean!itkat!ollipop!arshmallow!ougat!reo''!'-Oa99
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DckxDsMgDADAr8QTQ9UH5BVVx47GsRIrBiMDjXg9yXrnTN2r/HHOF/6@oRfCk8Fyb0CK4uA2DCTv7NEZt6d4kKUIxAs9kpaKebuEDmDVERkzSDuxgalKsQLo9UioahdY359wthAgvD@4rnMGCzc)

- saved 11 bytes thanks to [@Mr.Xcoder's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140081/59523)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 117 bytes

Port of my [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140076/59487).

```
"upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,ce cream sandwich,ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo"\,cQ.o67-@+
```

**[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=%22upcake%2Conut%2Cclair%2Croyo%2Cingerbread%2Coneycomb%2Cce+cream+sandwich%2Cellybean%2Citkat%2Collipop%2Carshmallow%2Cougat%2Creo%22%5C%2CcQ.o67-%40%2B&input=%22C%22&warnings=0)**

Encoded as hex codes, the new technique of golfing in Pyke, it would be **116 bytes**:

```
22 75 70 63 61 6B 65 2C 6F 6E 75 74 2C 63 6C 61 69 72 2C 72 6F 79 6F 2C 69 6E 67 65 72 62 72 65 61 64 2C 6F 6E 65 79 63 6F 6D 62 2C 63 65 20 63 72 65 61 6D 20 73 61 6E 64 77 69 63 68 2C 65 6C 6C 79 62 65 61 6E 2C 69 74 6B 61 74 2C 6F 6C 6C 69 70 6F 70 2C 61 72 73 68 6D 61 6C 6C 6F 77 2C 6F 75 67 61 74 2C 72 65 6F 22 5C 2C 63 51 EF 36 37 2D 40 2B
```

(Paste in and check `Use hex encoding?`).

Comment: Pyke needs an "Android releases" builtin right?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It has Pokemons, so why not?

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>131</s>, <s>126</s>, <s>123</s>, <s>112</s>, 178 bytes

```
grep(paste0('^',scan(,'')),c("Cupcake","Donut","Eclair","Froyo","Gingerbread","Honeycomb","Ice Cream Sandwich","Jellybean","Kitkat","Lollipop","Marshmallow","Nougat","Oreo"),v=T)
```

Thanks for @Mark for saving 5 + 8 + 3 bytes

Answer (score 1):

### [C#](http://csharppad.com/gist/7e894e195de97060659364635cbae838), <s>147</s> <s>136</s> 129 bytes

---

#### Data

- **Input** `Char` `c` The first letter of the version name
- **Output** `String` The full name of the version

---

#### Golfed

```cs
// Requires the input to be uppercase.
// This is the one counting for the challange
c=>c+"upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,ce Cream Sandwich,ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo".Split(',')[c-67];

// Optional. Requires the input to be lowercase.
c=>c+"upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,ce Cream Sandwich,ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo".Split(',')[c-99];

// Optional. Works with both uppercase and lowercase with the additional cost of 10 bytes.
c=>c+"upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,ce Cream Sandwich,ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo".Split(',')[c-(c<99?67:99)];
```

---

#### Ungolfed

```cs
c =>
    c + "upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,ce Cream Sandwich,ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo"
        .Split( ',' )[ c - 67 ];
```

---

#### Ungolfed readable

```cs
// Takes a char 
c =>
    // Appends the input letter to...
    c + 
    
    // ... the name in the resulting index of the subtraction of the char with 67 ('C'), or with 99 ('c') for the lowercase version
    "upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,ce Cream Sandwich,ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo"
        .Split( ',' )[ c - 67 ];

// Takes a char 
c => 
    // Appends the input letter to...
    c + 
    
    // ... the name in the resulting index of the subtraction of the char with 67 ('C') if the char is uppercase ( 'C' == 67, 'O' == 79 )
    //    or with 99 ('c') if the char is lowercase ( 'c' == 99, 'o' == 111 )
    "upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,ce Cream Sandwich,ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo"
        .Split( ',' )[ c - ( c < 99 ? 67 : 99 ) ];
```

---

#### Full code

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestBench {
    public static class Program {
        private static Func<Char, String> f = c =>
            c + "upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,ce Cream Sandwich,ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo"
                .Split( ',' )[ c - 67 ];
        
        static void Main( string[] args ) {
            List<Char>
                testCases = new List<Char>() {
                    'C',
                    'D',
                    'E',
                    'F',
                    'G',
                    'H',
                    'I',
                    'J',
                    'K',
                    'L',
                    'M',
                    'N',
                    'O',
                };
            
            foreach(Char testCase in testCases) {
                Console.WriteLine($" Input: {testCase}\nOutput: {f(testCase)}\n");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Releases

- **v1.0** - `147 bytes` - Initial solution.
- **v1.1** - `-11 bytes` - *Borrowed* [Olivier Grégoire's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140164/52814) idea.
- **v1.2** - `- 7 bytes` - Changed the function input from explicit to implicit.

---

#### Notes

- None

Comment: Could you save anything by removing the first letter from each name and appending the string you retrieve from the array to the input character?

Comment: `(char c)` can just be `c`

Answer (score 1):

### R, <strike>169</strike> 155 bytes

```
sub(paste0(".*(",scan(,""),"[^A-Z]+).*"),"\\1","CupcakeDonutEclairFroyoGingerbreadHoneycombIce cream sandwichJellybeanKitkatLollipopMarshmallowNougatOreo")
```

Answer (score 1):

## Dyalog APL, 125 bytes

```
{⍵/⍨⍞=⎕A[+\⍵∊⎕A]}'ABCupcakeDonutEclairFroyoGingerbreadHonecombIce cream sandwichJellybeanKitkatLollipopMarshmallowNougatOreo'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcs9CsIwGIDhq3TrIMUTONT6/3sAdfiahjb0a76QpJQiriJCxcXV2Qt4oVykxvF94AWFUdYCUh4xBGME63v3eLnr8@y679B1H9e9R17iw@Doxd3u/zhdwnic1IpBySckazv1t9AzTS3Nhcy5TjWHbEGSM6rSJeMB81AFBmTWCFasOGKbcpBrYUuwG0IUitQWtCkqQKRmR3UOdq85hX2f/AA)

### How?

- `⍵∊⎕A` `⍵` (the long string) with 1 for capital letters, 0 for lowercase/spaces.
- `+\` Group (returning numbers) ⍵ by capital letters.
- `⎕A[...]` The capital letter signified by a number
- `⍵/⍨⍞=`  The group signified by that number
- `{...}'...'` Set `⍵` to the long string

Comment: Clever approach.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 168 bytes

```c
main(){puts(memchr("Cupcake\0Donut\0Eclair\0Froyo\0Gingerbread\0Honeycomb\0Ice cream sandwich\0Jellybean\0Kitkat\0Lollipop\0Marshmallow\0Nougat\0Oreo",getchar(),117));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcy7CoNAEEDRXxErBQNjlSJl3u8fmGYcB13c3ZHVRSTk241p74HLm4Z5WRwZn@WfPo5D5sRxG7J0H3umThAO6uOIcGRLJiCcgs6KcDa@kVAFoRrhol5mVlchXFkSXqtLBvL1ZLhFuIm1cyXkEe5m7Gi9PdRa02uP8KQwtI6s1QnhpbH58zuIpkUjI7cUsrwoy22e777Lcv4B)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>136</strike> 134 bytes

```powershell
param($c)$c+('upcake0onut0clair0royo0ingerbread0oneycomb0ce cream sandwich0ellybean0itkat0ollipop0arshmallow0ougat0reo'-split0)[$c-99]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY1BCoQwDAC/4kGosgi5@hbxkMagxbQpaUV8fbfXGZjJ@rKVi0Vay2gYp5HmkX6TezLhzaDpqUCCwcD0UwjpZPPGeHTFH2n0QDxQJ3EomI430AW993nGBKHeWEFFQtYM2FcRRfQFfc4ujNUtJUuoMG8jLeu6t9amjS603amb/w)

Takes a `[char]` input character, in lowercase, and outputs in lowercase.

-2 thanks to AdmBorkBork's suggestion to `-split0` instead of `-split','`.

Comment: You could use `0` as a separator and then `-split0` to save the quotes.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork good suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## VBA for Word, 163 bytes

```
a=left(ActiveDocument.Range.Text,1):?a+Split("upcake onut clair royo ingerbread oneycomb ce cream sandwich ellybean itkat ollipop arshmallow ougat reo")(asc(a)-67)
```

@tisaconundrum asked for Word.  The closest I can get is a port of VBA for Excel solution by @TaylorScott.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 271 characters

```
var i="Cupcake|Donut|Eclair|Froyo|Gingerbread|Honeycomb|Ice cream sandwich|Jellybean|Kitkat|Lollipop|Marshmallow|Nougat|Oreo";var s=i.Split('|');int b;var c=new char[12];for(b=0;b<12;b++){c[b]=s[b][0];}for(b=0;b<12;b++){if(Console.Read().ToString()[0]==c[b])return s[b];}
```

Accepts one character from the console input stream, then returns the correct version number. Please tell me if I've done anything wrong or omitted something that should be here, this is my first time golfing.

Comment: This is a good first submission, but it looks to be halfway between a function and a full program. Try using arrow notation (`x=>...`) to define a function and using `x` instead of `Console.Read()`.

Answer (score 0):

## [SimpleTemplate](https://github.com/ismael-miguel/SimpleTemplate), 183 bytes

This just simply checks if the first letter of the word is the same or not.
Nothing super fancy.

```
{@setl"Cupcake","Donut","Eclair","Froyo","Gingerbread","Honeycomb","Ice Cream Sandwich","Jellybean","Kitkat","Lollipop","Marshmallow","Nougat","Oreo"}{@eachl}{@ifargv.0 is_.0}{@echo_}
```

**Ungolded**:

```
{@// array with all the names}
{@set list "Cupcake", "Donut", "Eclair", "Froyo", "Gingerbread", "Honeycomb", "Ice Cream Sandwich", "Jellybean", "Kitkat", "Lollipop", "Marshmallow", "Nougat", "Oreo"}
{@each list as name}
    {@if argv.0 is name.0} {@// name.0 -> first character}
        {@echo name}
    {@/}
{@/}
```

Try it on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/002cfd9c5a84546dac3a656f6011b998ccfe33af

Answer (score 0):

## [Cinnamon Gum](https://github.com/quartata/cinnamon-gum), 118 bytes

Hexdump:

```
0000000: 6c0d cac9 1183 300c 05d0 5638 fd26 74cc  l.....0...V8.&t.
0000010: bed7 2084 020e b2c5 0818 c6dd 87eb 9b77  .. ............w
0000020: 80ac 93f0 a874 44e7 655d e804 15e3 1474  .....tD.e].....t
0000030: c637 bc3a 5dd0 a7d2 6bb4 a1dc d115 8317  .7.:]...k.......
0000040: ade2 b9a5 1b92 6823 bbe7 66e6 d26d 4906  ......h#..f..mI.
0000050: bae3 a766 b555 2ef4 c098 9691 177a c2dc  ...f.U.......z..
0000060: 2c4d 3ed1 0b99 631e 329b f946 6f14 5ffb  ,M>...c.2..Fo._.
0000070: 7d7c e0a1 fe07                           }|....
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBNa5UxEIX3/ooDgisdZvIxSbpwJYqLLu1OJJkkrei93VSE0v72a96@r@DGA4FAOE@eGft@PtfT/fnd7a/T5cJ7rqDGHVatQCR7eGYDx86I6jNmd4oUzICftIXXucn05oFevQBkIdroCY5zADseaM4iOEuGae/IaTSUlhJABPonv3eEW4jM1VD8ZNScAkIYCRpjx8gcIHF4SFgPe//hA42v@21H@IUw9QnNfEXsS7@m7qCtBVTphi4Skb1sFomutvaPQ2NHhIWofTi0UiOkldXOzqO1TUWHYq2iIxTWw4LuXhNNotPnAxG3XdSlWpMqWowRbswA45JRtAgkpQpzy2dDTPpyKDz@tdCFcBY6/OgCbqVAvQx4VxpmCQqdEhDnbMDb6/era@SIPt7TtwORFiL1ZBhcBXPwGvm/eX7avr9cPv0B)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 133+1 bytes

```php
<?=$argn,[upcake,onut,clair,royo,ingerbread,oneycomb,"ce Cream Sandwich",ellybean,itkat,ollipop,arshmallow,ougat,reo][ord($argn)-67];
```

no TiO this time. Run as pipe with `-nR`.

Answer (score 0):

## SQL, 2017, 206 bytes

Assuming a function/procedure would have to be created otherwise you can't take input.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE X(@x VARCHAR)AS SELECT*FROM STRING_SPLIT('Cupcake,Donut,Eclair,Froyo,Gingerbread,Honeycomb,Ice cream sandwich,Jellybean,Kitkat,Lollipop,Marshmallow,Nougat,Oreo',',') WHERE value like @x+'%'
```

Cannot find a place to show this version online so there's a "slightly" more version-friendly submission

## SQL, 244 bytes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Y(@y VARCHAR,@x VARCHAR(999)='CupcakeDonutEclairFroyoGingerbreadHoneycombIce cream sandwichJellybeanKitkatLollipopMarshmallowNougatOreoP')AS SELECT STUFF(STUFF(@x,CHARINDEX(CHAR(ASCII(@y)+1),@x),999,''),1,CHARINDEX(@y,@x)-1,'')
```

Things to note, this is on a case-sensitive database therefore the delimiter could be the capital letter.

Explanation

```
Database is case-sensitive
Inner STUFF - removes everything from the the next capital letter in alphabet
Outer STUFF - removes everything before the input capital letter
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8fff8/3) worked example, not able to show a case sensitive database online so changed to a comma delimited list that works the same.